# How to restrict many routes using a contraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of me having to create 2 Rails apps, I want to segregate these 2 apps using route constraints.

I have a **blog** and **help** section:

```
class BlogHostContraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain = 'blog'
  end
end

class HelpHostContraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain = 'help'
  end
end
```

I want to make sure that all the routes for my blog are ONLY visible when the BlogConstraint matches, and the same for the blog contraint.

What I mean is, if I am on the blog subdomain, if I add a route in the URL it shouldn't render or conflict with any of the routes for the help subdomain routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw.do
  # blog
  get '/' => 'blog#index', constraints: BlogHostContraint
  ..

  # help
  get '/' => 'help#index', constraints: HelpHostConstraint
end
```

I know how to use contraints but only with a single route or a resources route like:

resources :users, constraints: SomeConstraintHere

How can I group a bunch of routes together with a constain, something like:

```
BlogConstraint do 
  get '..'
  get '...'
  post '...'
end
```

Is this possible?

One of the reasons I have to do this is I want nice URLS generated that start at the root for each area blog and help.

I don't want:

help.example.com/help/index
help.example.com/help/page/1

I want:

```
help.example.com/
help.example.com/page/1   # help_controller#page
```

and the same potentially for blog like:

```
blog.example.com/
blog.example.com/page/1   # blog_controller#page
```

I don't want other suggestions if it goes again having nice urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it to a `constraints` block:

```
constraints BlogConstraint do
  get '..'
  get '...'
  post '...'
end
```

I also think that your `matches?` implementations are incorrect. Those are supposed to return a boolean value, and you're returning an assignment instead.

```
class BlogHostContraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    # Use a comparison operator instead of an assignment operator.
    request.subdomain == 'blog'
  end
end
```